# What exactly is the reference DC parameter for GetWinMetaFileBits() used for?

Tags: winapi, graphics, gdi, resolution, metafile

I was under the impression that classic Win16 metafiles had no embedded size or resolution information (unless there is a [`METAFILEPICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) header or similar) - what does [`GetWinMetaFileBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) use the reference DC for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's well documented in the SDK article:

> This function converts an **enhanced
>   metafile** into a Windows-format
>   metafile so that its picture can be
>   displayed in an application that
>   recognizes the older format.
>
> The system uses the reference device
>   context to determine the **resolution of
>   the converted metafile**.

and

> A **Windows-format metafile** does not
>   contain a comprehensive header that
>   describes the original picture
>   dimensions, the resolution of the
>   device on which the picture was
>   created, an optional text description,
>   or an optional palette.

Comment: Does this mean that the coordinates of the operations stored in the resulting metafile are scaled by the ratio of the resolution in the EMF and the resolution of the reference device?